# How to fill a Map with the fields of another map?

Tags: map

```
Map<String, String> SecondMap= new Map<String, String>();
SecondMap.put('IndexValue', 'Value');

Map <String,Map <String,String>> FirstMap= new Map <String,Map<String,String>>();
FirstMap.put('IndexValue', new Map<String, String>());

for(String key1:FirstMap.keySet()) {
  for(String key2:FirstMap.get(key1).keySet()) {
    for(SecondMap.put(FirstMap.put(key1).get(key2))) {

    }
  }
}
```

I have two maps both have the parameters to insert, I need to insert the parameters of the secod map in the first map, I tried to create these loops but I did not succeed

Answer (score 2):

The method [`putAll()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) copies all of the key-value pairs from a Map into another Map.

```
Map<String, String> mapOne = new Map<String, String>{ 'Test' => 'Test!' };
Map<String, String> mapTwo = new Map<String, String>{ 'Foo' => 'Bar' };

mapOne.putAll(mapTwo);
// mapOne now equals { 'Test' => 'Test!', 'Foo' => 'Bar' }
```

It's not clear whether you're operating with a nested Map or not. If you are, and you're trying to add keys to a second-level (nested) Map, simply obtain the nested Map to which you wish to add values and call `putAll()` on that instance.